# SNMP Port Channel Monitoring

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, etherchannel

I am struggling to find an appropriate OID that will allow me to monitor the status of a port channels member mode status's.

We have several scenarios where equipment is connected to a MUX and the long haul fiber behind the MUX goes down (Interfaces on our gear do not go down). For non-aggregate interfaces I typically monitor to see if MAC addresses are being learned on the interface, however this will not work for a port channel.

We see this in logs on equipment we monitor detects a circuit issue:

`ETH_PORT_CHANNEL-5-PORT_SUSPENDED`

If anyone is aware of an OID (Or can confirm this type of monitoring is absolutely not possible with snmpwalks), I would be grateful.

EDIT: The particular piece of hardware I am monitoring is a Cisco Nexus, however we do have a variety of hardware from multiple vendors, so if there is a way to monitor this type of situation with standard MIB's (IEEE, IETF, RFC, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a particular hardware platform you're trying to monitor, but by message format I believe this is Cisco.

With Cisco's you could get monitoring information for portchannels out of cisco-port-channel-mib and IEEE8023-LAG-MIB, depending on platform and software.

We also used to check channel integrity in old days by monitoring ifHighSpeed (that's old-school Cisco IF-MIB) for the port-channel, it changes when physical members are falling out of Po.

Comment: I've browsed IEEE8023-LAG-MIB, but do not see anything the member interface modes. I haven't seen anywhere where the member's are enumerated and what their mode is (suspended, operational, etc).

The problem with ifHighSpeed is that while the member is up/up its HighSpeed will always be 1000. Though it is up/up, the port-channel marks it suspended due to issues beyond the member interface.

Comment: Member interface modes encoded in this MIB in `dot3adAggPortActorOperState` within `dot3adAggPortTable`, they are encoded as 8bit binary values where each bit represents true/false for certain phases of LACP finite state machine. You should look into it and see if your topology issues trigger some changes there..